# Vedo not clearing the plot and not closing the window (Python)

Tags: python, vtk, vedo

I am trying to create some scientific visualisations using `Python`. I use the `vedo` library.  The plot is not getting cleared and the window is not closing. Please help me diagnose this issue.

I have a set of `vtk` files in sequential order and I am trying to create an animation. This is my code:

```py
from vedo import *
import os

vtk_files = [file for file in os.listdir() if file.endswith('.vtk')]
vtk_files.sort()  

# Create a Plotter instance
plotter = Plotter()

for i in vtk_files:

    print(i)
 
    mesh = load(i,unpack=True, force=True)

    plotter += mesh

    plotter.show()

    plotter.clear()

    plotter.close()
```

While going through the loop, a plot window pops up showing the first vtk file and then it freezes. The plot is not getting cleared and the window is not closing. That means the `plotter.clear()` and `plotter.close()` commands are not working. When I manually close the plot window the code jumps to the next `vtk` file, but it doesn't show the plot as the plot window is already closed. I have the same problem with another visualisation package. Is it something with plotting module (`Pyqt` or any widget) which these libraries use?  Please help.

I have checked the `vtk` and `vedo` documentation but I can't find what's wrong. I have gone through a lot of questions on stack overflow and github but I still can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You are closing the plotter inside the loop.. Consider these options:

```py
from vedo import *
meshes = load("letter_*.vtk") # sort is done automatically
plotter = Plotter(axes=1)
for i, m in enumerate(meshes):
    m.pos([i*2000, 0, 0]).color(i)
plotter.show(meshes).close()
```

[image]

Another option:

```py
import time
from vedo import *
meshes = load("letter_*.vtk")
plotter = Plotter(interactive=False)
plotter.show() # show the empty window
for i, m in enumerate(meshes):
    m.color(i)
    plotter.remove(meshes).add(m)
    plotter.reset_camera().render()
    time.sleep(0.5)
plotter.interactive().close()
```

will visualise your meshes one by one. Note that objects can also be removed by name e.g.:

`mesh.name = "jack"` then `plotter.remove("jack")` will remove it.